# Sql Query to get the active products during a certain timeframe

Tags: sql-server, query

I have the following table

```
Create table #products
(
productId int,
regionId int,
date datetime,
active bit
)

insert into #products values
(1,20,'10/10/2020',1),(1,20,'12/10/2022',0),(1,20,'5/8/2023',1),
(2,20,'11/11/2020',0),(2,20,'12/12/2022',1),(2,20,'5/8/2023',0),
(3,20,'10/10/2020',1),(3,20,'12/10/2022',0),(3,20,'5/8/2023',1)
```

I'm trying to find out which products were active between March 1, 2023, and March 30, 2023. Looking at the data provided, only product ID 2 was active during that period. How can I write a SQL query to accurately retrieve this information? I've tried a few queries, but I'm not getting the results I expect. Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: What when it started or ended in March 2023, should it be included or excluded?

Comment: if it was active during march then that product should be included.

Comment: Have you considered system temporal tables? Documentation at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Search for a row whose time is less than range end, status is active, and lead of time is greater than range start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #products (
  productId INT,
  regionId INT,
  date DATETIME,
  active BIT
  );
INSERT INTO #products VALUES
(1,20,'10/10/2020',1),(1,20,'12/10/2022',0),(1,20,'5/8/2023',1),
(2,20,'11/11/2020',0),(2,20,'12/12/2022',1),(2,20,'5/8/2023',0),
(3,20,'10/10/2020',1),(3,20,'12/10/2022',0),(3,20,'5/8/2023',1),
(4,20,'01/01/2020',1),
(5,20,'01/01/2020',0);
SELECT *, LEAD(date) OVER (PARTITION BY productId ORDER BY date) nextdate
FROM #products;
```

| productId | regionId | date | active | nextdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00.000 | True | 2022-12-10 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 20 | 2022-12-10 00:00:00.000 | False | 2023-05-08 00:00:00.000 |
| 1 | 20 | 2023-05-08 00:00:00.000 | True | *null* |
| 2 | 20 | 2020-11-11 00:00:00.000 | False | 2022-12-12 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 20 | 2022-12-12 00:00:00.000 | True | 2023-05-08 00:00:00.000 |
| 2 | 20 | 2023-05-08 00:00:00.000 | False | *null* |
| 3 | 20 | 2020-10-10 00:00:00.000 | True | 2022-12-10 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 20 | 2022-12-10 00:00:00.000 | False | 2023-05-08 00:00:00.000 |
| 3 | 20 | 2023-05-08 00:00:00.000 | True | *null* |
| 4 | 20 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | True | *null* |
| 5 | 20 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | False | *null* |

```
DECLARE @from DATE = '03/01/2023';
DECLARE @till DATE = '03/31/2023';

WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, COALESCE(LEAD(date) OVER (PARTITION BY productId ORDER BY date), 
                     DATEADD(dd, 1, @till)) nextdate
  FROM #products
  )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE date <= @till
  AND @from <= nextdate
  AND active = 1;
```

| productId | regionId | date | active | nextdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 20 | 2022-12-12 00:00:00.000 | True | 2023-05-08 00:00:00.000 |
| 4 | 20 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | True | 2023-04-01 00:00:00.000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/01y0JrYj)

If you want to process your data for each region separately then expand PARTITION BY expression accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

One more way:

```
WITH ActiveDateRange AS (
    SELECT ProductID, date as BeginDate, EndDate
    FROM #products AS P OUTER APPLY (SELECT MIN(date) AS EndDate FROM #Products p2 where p2.productid = p.productid and p.date<p2.date) a
    WHERE P.active = 1)
SELECT p.*, EndDate
FROM #products p inner join ActiveDateRange ADR on p.productID = ADR.productID and p.date = ADR.BeginDate
WHERE BeginDate <= '20230301' AND EndDate >= '20230330'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked my query and based on the suggestion provided by Akina this is what I have. Let me know if you think this query yields the correct results.

```
Declare @from date = '03/01/2021'
Declare @to   date = '03/31/2021'

;WITH MaxActiveDates AS (
SELECT productId
      ,MAX(date) AS max_active_date
  FROM #products
 WHERE active = 1
   AND regionId = 20
   AND date < @to
 GROUP BY productId
),
InactiveNextDates AS (
SELECT p.productId
      ,MIN(p.date) AS next_inactive_date
  FROM #products       p
  JOIN MaxActiveDates  m 
    ON p.productId   = m.productId
 WHERE p.active      = 0
   AND p.regionId    = 20
   AND p.date        > m.max_active_date
   AND p.date       >= @from
 GROUP BY p.productId
)
SELECT p.*
  FROM #products p
  JOIN MaxActiveDates m 
    ON p.productId = m.productId
  JOIN InactiveNextDates i 
    ON p.productId = i.productId
   AND p.date = m.max_active_date
```